# Calling function 'makeDecorator', function calls are not supported

Tags: json, angular, typescript, npm, simplemodal

Solved by @alexzuza. See his answer below - big ups!
Basically, remove the node_modules folder from the ng2-opd-popup folder, and edit the `src/tsconfig.app.json` to match the path. See comments also for link to rimraf setup, to automatically exclude the node_modules from being installed with npm install.

I get this error:

> ERROR in Error encountered resolving symbol values statically. Calling
>   function 'makeDecorator', function calls are not supported. Consider
>   replacing the function or lambda with a reference to an exported
>   function

The solution found [here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/3854), is not working - im running angular v. 4.3.

package.json:

```
PopupModule.forRoot(),
```

tsconfig.json:

```
"paths": {
  "@angular/*": ["node_modules/@angular/*"]
},
```

tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "paths": {
      "@angular/common": ["../node_modules/@angular/common"],
      "@angular/compiler": ["../node_modules/@angular/compiler"],
      "@angular/core": ["../node_modules/@angular/core"],
      "@angular/forms": ["../node_modules/@angular/forms"],
      "@angular/platform-browser": ["../node_modules/@angular/platform-browser"],
      "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": ["../node_modules/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic"],
      "@angular/router": ["../node_modules/@angular/router"],
      "@angular/http": ["../node_modules/@angular/http"]
    },
    "lib": [
      "es2017",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

tsconfig.app.json:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "paths": {
      "@angular/*": ["../node_modules/@angular/*"]
    },
    "lib": [
      "es2017",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

My file structure. [image: File structure]

The package im trying to use: [ng2-opd-popup](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-opd-popup)

Somebody got a solution for this, or maybe a better package to use?

Comment: The issue is with `ng2-opd-popup` unfortunately. You can manually copy over the TypeScript code to build locally with your project. To fix the module they would have to remove `@angular/*` from `dependencies` during build. There may be another way to fix it, but I'm not sure.

Comment: What a shame actually, the package seems nice. Do you have any suggestions for other modal packages?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change **src/tsconfig.app.json** like:

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/app",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "module": "es2015",
    "types": [],
    "paths": {
      "@angular/*": ["../node_modules/@angular/*"] <=== add this
    }
  },
  "exclude": [
    "test.ts",
    "**/*.spec.ts"
  ]
}
```

**You should use `..` because `baseUrl` refers to `src` folder**

https://github.com/alexzuza/angular-cli-make-decorator-fix

It should work for aot, but for jit mode you have to remove `node_modules/ng2-opd-popup/node_modules folder`

[image]

Comment: Still getting the error mate :( You had this package working on Angular 4.3?

Comment: Yes, it's working for me. Please create minimal repo to reproduce it

Comment: I don't know how to do that sorry. But it shouldnt be necessary, i just need to edit the tsconfig.json, and tsconfig.app.json files with the paths - right?

Comment: If yes then add `paths` option only in `src/tsconfig.app.json` as i wrote in my answer

Comment: If im using cli, i dont need to edit the src/tsconfig.json?

Comment: Still doesn't work with editing the `src/tsconfig.app.json` only.

Comment: Which version angular-cli are you using? Can you add screenshot of folder structure. tsconfig  is a root file http://take.ms/1jr7E

Comment: Using ´  @angular/cli": "1.3.2 ´ - my file structure is edit'ed to the main post.

Comment: As far as i can see, the image structure you linked to, is the exact same as mine.

Comment: A side question: which version of the cli are you on, and what editor are you using?

Comment: screenshot is from VSCode, "@angular/cli": "1.4.7",

Comment: Ok. So i've cloned your repo, same error occurred: "Uncaught Error: Unexpected value '[object Object]'"

Comment: Compiled successfully - nothing out of the ordinary ng serve. Using chrome btw.

Comment: `It should work for aot, but for jit mode you have to remove node_modules/ng2-opd-popup/node_modules folder`

Comment: Yours is actually working if i remove the node-modules folder inside the package. Thank you! What do you recommend i do for my app? Is there some way to exclude that package when running npm install, so i dont have to manually delete the folder every time i want to ng serve/build?

Comment: https://github.com/alexzuza/angular-cli-make-decorator-fix/commit/74b9c422a0dc36288f063c57713a0b68aab19de1

Comment: You're a f*cking god man. Thank you so much! I'll edit the main post with answers, and mark yours as the solver. I really appreciate the help! You have a good day, sir!